# how to group and sum data in foreach javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have a data in the form of an array object. I will group the data and sum the total based on date and code

```
const data = [
{code: 8, date:"2022-03-24", total:4},
{code: 8, date:"2022-03-24", total:8},
{code: 8, date:"2022-03-25", total:2},
{code: 9, date:"2022-03-24", total:4},
{code: 9, date:"2022-03-25", total:2},
{code: 9, date:"2022-03-25", total:1},]
```

results to be expected

```
const result = [
{code: 8, date:"2022-03-24", total:12},
{code: 8, date:"2022-03-25", total:2},
{code: 9, date:"2022-03-24", total:4},
{code: 9, date:"2022-03-25", total:3},]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried reduce, but I'm not getting the results. I don't really understand reduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `reduce` usually for these grouping problems. I'm taking the combination of `code` and `date` to group. something like `"8|2022-03-24"`.

This is how the intermediate object will look like

```js
{
  8|2022-03-24: {
    code: 8,
    date: "2022-03-24",
    total: 12
  },
  8|2022-03-25: {
    code: 8,
    date: "2022-03-25",
    total: 2
  },
  9|2022-03-24: {
    code: 9,
    date: "2022-03-24",
    total: 4
  },
  9|2022-03-25: {
    code: 9,
    date: "2022-03-25",
    total: 3
  }
}
```

From that object I'm taking the values using `Object.values`

```js
const data = [
{code: 8, date:"2022-03-24", total:4},
{code: 8, date:"2022-03-24", total:8},
{code: 8, date:"2022-03-25", total:2},
{code: 9, date:"2022-03-24", total:4},
{code: 9, date:"2022-03-25", total:2},
{code: 9, date:"2022-03-25", total:1},]

let grouped = Object.values(data.reduce((acc,{code,date,total})=>{
    acc[code+'|'+date] = acc[code+'|'+date] || {code,date,total:0}
  acc[code+'|'+date].total+=total
  return acc;
},{}))

console.log(grouped)
```